# Laravel: Simplest way to filter multiple controllers with one rule?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I have a users table with a field called 'role', 0 - regular users, 1 - admin.

I have multiple controllers that only the admin uses.  What is the easiest way to only allow users with a role of 1 to use them?  I will have all these controllers in a folder called 'admin'.

Currently I have an if test in my routes.php file like this

```
if(Auth::user()->role == 1) {

    Route::resource('someRes', 'someResController');

}
```

But I have come to realize this is the wrong way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned, use route groups, allows you to group routes and filter:

```
Route::group(array('before' => 'checkUser'), function()
{
   Route::resource('someRes', 'someResController');
   Route::resource('anotherRes', 'anotherResController');
});
```

Then in your filters:

```
Route::filter('checkUser', function()
{
    if(Auth::user()->role !== 1)
    {
        return Redirect::route('loginRoute')->with('message', 'Authorization required');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Just transform your check into route filter: http://laravel.com/docs/routing#route-filters

Then group restricted routes with route group and apply that filter on it: http://laravel.com/docs/routing#route-groups